# How to write a function which returns an optional array of strings from a dictionary variable?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, option-type

I have a function that is written
`func synonyms(for:) --> [String : [String?]]`
and I want to make it so that it returns an array of optionals (Strings). I have a dictionary variable (`[String : [String]]`)that looks like a Word (key) and array (value, anywhere between 4-6 different synonyms for the word). 
In trying to achieve this, I thought in order to return the synonyms for a passed in word I would actually need to tell the computer to find the matching key from my `userinput` (TextField, ViewController, and I am using UI Delegate). To do that, I use a for-in loop. The problem here is that the compiler says "for" is a "for loop" when actually it's for my argument/parameter for my synonym function..
What do I write in the inside of my synonym function?

In order to return the synonyms for a passed in word in this function I need to tell the computer to find the matching key from my userinput (TextField, ViewController, and I am using UI Delegate). I tried using a for-in loop. The problem is that the compiler says "for" is a "for loop" when actually it's for my argument/parameter for my synonym function.

```swift
    func synonyms(for: String) -> [String: [String?]] {
        let synonynmsAre = "your synonyms \(for) are)"
        return synonynmsAre
    }

    print(synonyms(for: "swift"))
    synonyms(for: "swift")
```

your synonyms are `Optional(["abrupt", "expeditious", "hasty", "nimble", "quick", "rapid", "speedy", "sudden", "unexpected"])`
but, without the brackets and the Optional there. I want this also to display in the TextView in my iOS app. I'm using the latest version of XCode and also the latest version of Swift.

Comment: What are you asking ? What's the problem? can't you show your synonyms into a UILabel ? can't you write the function? Anyway, you can't use keyword as parameter name or label, this is in every language you use, so you have to change "for" label of your function

Comment: Why optional (`[String?]`)? If there are 4-6 synonyms there are no optionals. And even if there are no synonyms the array is just empty.

Comment: @Andrew21111 you can use `for` as a label, but not as a parameter name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
// Basically where you store the synonyms
let synonymsDictionary = [
    "swift": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
    "objective-c": ["NSFoo", "NSBar", "NSBaz"]
]

// Just return an optional array here
func synonyms(for word: String) -> [String]? {
    return synonymsDictionary[word]
}


// how to use

if let possibleSynonyms = synonyms(for: "swift") {
    print(possibleSynonyms.joined(separator: ", ")) // prints foo, bar, baz
    // or
    someLabel.text = possibleSynonyms.joined(separator: ", ")
}
```